# Sonar analysis difference in two version(5.6 & 6.3)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.6, sonarqube6.3

We have two Environment of Sonar having versions (5.6 & 6.3).

We have set up all the sonar quality profiles,types,rules,severity identical in both environments.

But when we do analysis from both versions on the same repository, we are getting difference in the sonar analysis and its issues severities.

Please help us to find where the issue may persists.

Comment: there are also fixes to rules regarding false positives... question is, are the plugins the same version?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking:

only because you have the same version of SonarQube, does not mean that you are using the same Plugins.

Even tough the plugins have the same rules, they are also differ from release to release. Plugin developers find bugs in the rules, or there is a big change of severity, and movement from category "bugs" to "code smell"

so, as long as your server is not running the same plugin versions - you can not compare the outcome of those two!